# How to get value only after change

Tags: mysql, sql, datetime, gaps-and-islands

Let's say I have a simple database like:

```
CREATE TABLE test (
  id INT,
  time datetime,
  status integer
);
```

and some data:

```
INSERT INTO test (id, time, status) VALUES (1, '2020-11-09 10:00', 256);
INSERT INTO test (id, time, status) VALUES (2, '2020-11-09 11:00', 256);
INSERT INTO test (id, time, status) VALUES (3, '2020-11-09 11:20', 512);
INSERT INTO test (id, time, status) VALUES (4, '2020-11-09 11:35', 512);
INSERT INTO test (id, time, status) VALUES (5, '2020-11-09 11:40', 1024);
INSERT INTO test (id, time, status) VALUES (6, '2020-11-09 11:45', 1024);
INSERT INTO test (id, time, status) VALUES (7, '2020-11-09 11:48', 1024);
INSERT INTO test (id, time, status) VALUES (8, '2020-11-09 12:00', 0);
INSERT INTO test (id, time, status) VALUES (9, '2020-11-09 12:01', 0);
INSERT INTO test (id, time, status) VALUES (10, '2020-11-09 12:05', 0);
INSERT INTO test (id, time, status) VALUES (11, '2020-11-09 12:07', 0);
INSERT INTO test (id, time, status) VALUES (12, '2020-11-09 12:09', 512);
```

What I want to do, is to have only the rows when status have changed.
Simple DISTINCT gives me only 1 value so is not that easy:

```
SELECT DISTINCT(status), time FROM test;
```

**So my expected result should have id:
1, 3, 5, 8 and 12**

Do I need grouping? Will appreciate the help.

Here is SQL Fiddle:
https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/nixj1LCKLJCfeXk9q7233P/0

Comment: Note that DISTINCT is not a function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `lag()`:

```
select *
from (
    select t.*, lag(status) over(order by time) lag_status
    from test t
) t
where not status <=> lag_status
```

This requires MySQL 8.0. In earlier versions, one approach uses a correlated subquery:

```
select t.*
from test t
where not status <=> (
    select t1.status
    from test t1
    where t1.time < t.time 
    order by t1.time desc
    limit 1
)
```

https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/nixj1LCKLJCfeXk9q7233P/1

Comment: Interesting approach, thank you for fast response, both codes works fine. I will probably use the second one - just for compatibility

Comment: @Tikky: the first query is much more efficient, use it as a priority! All major databases have been supporting window functions for a long time, only MySQL came late to that party...